# Creating HTML5 applications in SAP cloud platform

Tags: sapui5

I am new to SAP CP. I have built a webpage which has html, css and js files. I want to deploy the same in SAP CP and then do the backend (js) and bind to the hana database.

A few doubts regarding the same:

- Can I deploy the same as HTML5 apps in sapui5 or I need to package it
  as a war and deploy to Java apps?
- How can I Bind a database to the same?

Also please note that I have not selected any template from sapui5 its an custom project the whole idea is to run a htnl5 web app in sap CP.

Any guidance will be great.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use a war and deploy it as a Java app here as this is pure HTML5 app.

With HTML5, you would usually consume database content using REST API (OData for example) that you have exposed and not via direct SQL like you would do in Java with JDBC.

Therefore you won't bind a database to a HTML5 app, but a REST API endpoint that will provide the database service you expect to read/write etc from.

Comment: Thanks for the response, can I convert the same to a Hybrid app going forward ?

Comment: If you want to build an Hybrid, I definitely recommend you to use the SAPUI5 project Template. This will allow you to leverage the SAPUI5 controls etc that are responsive, and mobile compliant

Comment: Okay , So you suggest not to use a custom html5 app while going for hybrid apps and rather I should choose a sap ui5 project template?
Is there any reference you can point me to , I searched but could not find such resource explaining the same in detail.

Comment: Yes this will make your life much easier to start with the SAPUI5 template.

Comment: Have you checked the following https://blogs.sap.com/2018/05/22/creating-an-offline-crud-hybrid-mobile-app-in-sap-web-ide-full-stack-with-hybrid-application-toolkit/ )hope posting an external blog link is ok)